# Swift: как лучше загрузить два файла?

Tags: ios, swift

Я хочу загрузить 2 файла и показать их данные в 2 разных `strings`. Я пытаюсь сделать это так, и вроде все работает нормально. Но я думаю, что это не лучшее решение создавать 2 функции Может нужно обеднить их в одну а ссылки добавить в массив? Как сделать более элегантное решение?

```
var saleNumber1 = ""
var saleNumber2 = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        sale1()
        sale2()
}

func sale1() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/folder/sale1.txt")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            saleNumber1 = "\(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)"
        }

        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    func sale2() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/folder/sale2.txt")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            saleNumber2 = "\(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)"
        }

        task.resume()
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, ваше направление мысли верное. Можно сделать массив:

```
var links:[String] = ["http://example.com/folder/sale1.txt", "http://example.com/folder/sale2.txt"]
```

сделать один метод в который будет передаваться как-бы номер документа:

```
func download(num: Int){
let url = URL(string: links[num])!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
   guard let data = data else { return }
   switch num {
      case 1:
         saleNumber1 = "\(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)"
      case 2:
         saleNumber2 = "\(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)"
      default:
         print("не удалось распознать число")
}
}

task.resume()
}
```

так же я думаю что можно уйти от массива, так как у вас отличаются только порядковые номера документов, поэтому в методе можно напрямую вставлять номер документа в стринг:

```
let url = URL(string: String(format: "http://example.com/folder/sale@d.txt", num))!
```

[вот тут есть вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424637/create-string-template-in-swift) про template в swift. Ну а вызывать можно в цикле и просто передавать индекс цикла начиная с 1:

```
for index in 1...2 {
    download(index)
}
```